# "Однако" в данном случае не вводное?

Tags: вводные-слова

*Однако если тогда людей хотя бы кормили обещаниями о спасении рубля, то сейчас не делают даже этого.*

*Однако если тогда оценки компаний росли на новостях и слухах, то сейчас мы видим реальные двухзначные цифры роста выручки.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) В этих предложениях **ОДНАКО является присоединительным союзом**, так как вводное слово «однако» не может стоять в начале предложения.

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?id=58_504&layout=item

2) **Запятая на стыке присоединительного союза и подчинительного союза** может ставиться или не ставиться (для союза ОДНАКО чаще ставится).

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_36.htm#ppp_5

5. Постановка запятой между присоединительным союзом и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом зависит от значения союза.

3) В приведенном предложении запятая может не ставиться в связи **с отсутствием паузы** (в случае двойного союза ЕСЛИ...ТО).